# how to close the current form while manipulating an external component?

Tags: c#

I have a form that is not the main form of the program. I'm using LibVLC for C# for media reproduction in this form, so I have a visual MediaPlayer component. I'm handling the Mediaplayer_Stopped event as in the code below:

```
private void MediaPlayer_Stopped(object sender, EventArgs e){
     this.Close();
}
```

My intention is to close the current form when the Media Player assumes the status of stopped. However, when using "this.Close()" in this context, I am referring to MediaPlayer and not to the form.
The error I get when trying to run the code above is: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid thread operation:' Player 'control accessed from a thread other than the one on which it was created.'`

How can I close the form in this case?

Comment: Keep a reference to the form that you want to close, then call close on that.

Comment: how can I do this? Do you have a link, tutorial, image? I am at the very beginning of learning C#